# In a binary star system of two stars orbiting each other why are their distances to the barycenter inversely related to their masses?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Two stars, S1 and S2, orbit each other around a common center of mass, the barycenter.
M1 and M2 are their respective masses.
R1 and R2 are their respective distances from the barycenter.
D is the distance between their two orbital centers.
I found the following in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star

R1 = DxM2/(M1+M2)
R2 = DxM1/(M1+M2)

R1 = R2xM2/M1.

For example, M2/M1 = 10,
R1 = 10 times R2.

Why is this?
George

Comment: Well, I do not quite understand your question. The definition of the center of mass of a system is $\vec r\equiv (\sum_i m_i \vec r_i)/(\sum m_i)$. This gives precisely what you ask. Another question is why the center of mass is so important, e g why bodies in a two-body problem orbit around it. It is not quite clear what you are asking

Answer (score 4):

In any system formed by two point masses, the distance of each point mass to the common barycenter is inversely proportional to its mass.

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the positions of the point masses, $m_1$ and $m_2$ their masses, and $x_g$ the position of the barycenter.

By definition of barycenter:

$x_g=\frac{x_1·m_1+x_2·m_2}{m_1+m_2}$

And the distance from the point masses to the common barycenter:

$x_g-x_1=\frac{x_1·m_1+x_2·m_2}{m_1+m_2}-x_1=\frac{x_1·m_1+x_2·m_2}{m_1+m_2}-\frac{(m_1+m_2)·x_1}{m_1+m_2}=\frac{m_2·(x_2-x_1)}{m_1+m_2}=m_2·\frac{x_2-x_1}{m_1+m_2}$

$x_g-x_2=m_1·\frac{x_1-x_2}{m_1+m_2}$

Therefore:

$\frac{x_g-x_1}{m_2}=-\frac{x_g-x_2}{m_1}$

Or using your notation where $D=abs(x_1-x_2)$ and $R_i=abs(x_g-x_i)$

$R_1=\frac{D·m_2}{m_1+m_2}$

$R_2=\frac{D·m_1}{m_1+m_2}$

Answer (score 1):

Basic reason is simple. Both stars rotate around barycenter, so their relative centripetal forces pointing to COM must be equal (otherwise they will not get the same angular speed) :

$$ m_1r_1\omega ^{2} = m_2r_2\omega ^{2} \tag 1 $$,

so

$$ \frac {m_1}{m_2} = \frac {r_2}{r_1} \tag 2$$